# Flutter print a widget in a pdf page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have don't know how to print my widget into a pdf, I've tried multiple solution but no one has worked. Anyone know how can I print it?

Print Function

```
_generatePdfAndView(context, Bilancio bilancio) async {
// List<Bilancio> data = await bilanci.first;
final pdfLib.Document pdf = pdfLib.Document(deflate: zlib.encode);
pdf.addPage(
  pdfLib.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) => CardBilancio(bilancio: bilancio,),
            ),

);
final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final String path = '$dir/Scostamento_${DateTime.now().toString()}.pdf';
final File file = File(path);
file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => PdfViewerPage(path: path),
  ),
);
```

}

Thanks in advance or your help.